# Select Git branch for TeamCity Build

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm wondering how to select the branch to build against using Team City 8.1.

My VCS root (Git) is set to Default:  "master" and Branch specifications are

```
+:refs/heads/develop
+:refs/heads/feature/*
+:refs/heads/hotfix/*
+:refs/heads/master
+:refs/heads/release/*
```

I have a CI build set up that automatically builds anything that is checked in, which is working exactly how I want.

What I'd like to do is create a scheduled QA build/deployment against the "develop" branch.   I see that if I click the ellipsis next to the run button, I can choose the branch on the "Changes" tab, but I'm unable to determine how to make this "stick".  Is this possible, or am I going about this wrong?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Based on @biswajit-86 's feedback and some other information I found while googling this, I was able to get this to work.   Here's what I did (image-heavy, sorry).  It's based on Team City 8.2 which seems to be set up a little differently than the examples I came across.

1)  Set up a VCS root.  Key here is the `%BranchName%` parameter.

[image]

2)  Create a Build template and use the VCS root that was just created.  I also added an MSBuild step as all of my builds need to run this.

[image]

3)  Create a new build, based on the template.   As you can see here, the `%BrachName%` parameter that was created in step 1 is available.

[image]

4) If you need to change this later, it's available here

[image]

And that's pretty much it.  For my CI build, I left the branch name empty so any branch that is checked in triggers the MSBuild step.  For my QA build, I pass in "develop" as shown here and I have this set up on a daily schedule.   I also have a "release" build set up, but based on our naming conventions it looks like I need to update the build to point to the specific branch per release.

Comment: Teamcity should have this kind of feature ... It is a pitty its not there ... For subversion we could control this through checkout rules ... but not here ...

Comment: Why do I have to to dig inside the SO to find it? It should be available on the official TC manual. Thank you very much.

Comment: In version 9.1.5, I had to manually define a %BranchName% parameter in each build configuration. I also had to use that parameter to specify a unique checkout directory for each configuration. (The latter issue may have been due to peculiarities in our setup.) Apart from that, it was all quite simple and works fine.

Answer (score 8):

You can parameterize the "Ref name" of the git VCS setup. What this means is you declare a variable of the form `%variable.name%` in your build, create a build parameter under the "configuration parameter:" category.

For each build target set this value and you should be able to pick the specific branch that you want to run the target for.