# Teamcity branch name as prompt variable

Tags: teamcity-8.0

i am trying to pass default git branch as prompt parameter while starting the build. I have tried using environment variable and configuration variable. but some how its not working. Actually i want to build different branches as per user input. further this will be used as octopus deploy package.

Ashish

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Git branch for TeamCity Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415704/select-git-branch-for-teamcity-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use TeamCity with TFS and I would imagine it would be similar with GIT.  We have added a build configuration parameter:

```
Name: checkout.rules
Kind: Configuration parameter
Value: +:Branches/HOTFIX => .
```

The Value is a default value which can be overwritten.  Then under Version Control Settings, add a Checkout Rule which references the parameter:

```
%checkout.rules%
```