# Select Git branch for TeamCity Build Configuration

Tags: github, build, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I want to accomplish following  via teamcity in my CI box.

```
Master branch commit : Build and Release
Beta branch commit: Build and Release to Crashlytics
All other commits to any other branch: Build
```

(side note since most of our development branches may or may not contain a prefix, it makes it difficult to use "feature-*" branch naming)

Following this question [Select Git branch for TeamCity Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415704/select-git-branch-for-teamcity-build)

I have created a Configuration Parameters in my project settings

[image]

and then

my VCS root settings

[image]

Then I created a build template

[image]

When I created builds I made sure branch name is correct

[image]

I have also tried to edit Triggers

[image]

How ever this is not working because when I push a commit to Beta branch

I think because of `ref/heads/*` default build is running all the branches

and Beta and Master displays "Pending"

[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by talking to other developers and making sure that all development branches uses a prefix, in this case `XAAI-`

then in my VCS root settings

[image]

for triggers in each build configuration I make sure it only is triggered when that branch is checked in.

for example for QA (Betabuild)

[image]

***this is the tricky part , for Development branches I had to give an empty parameter, I dont know why (maybe because something needs to check default branch which is supposed to be ref/heads/*) but whatever the reason it is working.***

[image]

and then finally whole thing looks like this

[image]

That pending thing is still annoying but , I think at least it is working as I envisioned now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your builds to only trigger automatically when the default branch is pushed to, you can add a branch filter to the trigger like so `+:<default>`.

This is dependent on the assumption that you have setup the %BranchName% parameter in each build configuration correctly. IE, for your Default build, make the %BranchName% parameter = master.

As a side note, you will still see all pending changes for each branch, but the trigger will only run when you push to your default build if you add the branch filter. If you want to get rid of the pending changes for each branch, you'll need to setup your vcs root specfic for each configuration to filter out the branches all together.

Comment: If you do multiple  vcs roots how do you share the `Build Number` in between branches ?