# Teamcity not autobuild for develop branch

Tags: git, tfs, teamcity

I use for a C # project, Git since TFS.

When I make my changes, Teamcity detects the changes. But for only the development bran the build does not fire automatically. To know that the master works to him very well.

Do you have an idea ?

Below you will find the settings for the branch develop

1) My Teamcity dashboard

[image]

2) My config trigger

[image]

3) My config VCS

[image]

4) My branchs on tfs

[image]

Comment: Go to your build configuration and check the Version Control Settings page, at the bottom there is a "Allow builds in the default branch", is that checked? If it is you shouldn't need to specify a filter on your trigger, unless you've also configured your VCS root to have a branch specification (which is in addition to your default branch).

Comment: Basically, go check "Allow builds in the default branch", remove (if set) your branch specification (big textbox below "Default branch" in your VCS root), then go remove the filter on your VCS trigger. See if that helps.

Comment: So Allow builds in the default branch is checked, i have set trigger to +:* , and i have not area for specification branch (because my git come from tfs ? I don't know). one pending displays +1 but still no auto build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar thread for your reference here: [Select Git branch for TeamCity Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415704/select-git-branch-for-teamcity-build),  just try the solution mentioned in the thread:

> You can try to parameterize the "Ref name" of the git VCS setup. What
>   this means is you declare a variable of the form %variable.name% in
>   your build, create a build parameter under the "configuration
>   parameter:" category.
>
> For each build target set this value and you should be able to pick
>   the specific branch that you want to run the target for.

1. Set up a VCS root. Key here is the %BranchName% parameter.
2. Create a Build template and use the VCS root that was just created.
3. Create a new build, based on the template.