# Start build on old branch without new commit

Tags: teamcity

### Context

I have a project absed on a vcs root with the wildcard branch filter (`+:*`), meaning that it will trigger a build on every possible modification pushed to git.

Because we're on a migration process, our current projects have a lot of branches, and we want to start the build process on some of them.

### Issue

Because the `Run` button of the build starts a build with default branch (AKA master), we can't run a build on a given branch, the need being to have a select box with existing branches that you can select for the build.

### Already tried / Invalid solutions

A solution would be to push a dummy commit on each branch to trigger TC and make it see the branch, this way we could select the branch in the run options, but that's not a solution to us because pushing a dummy commit just for that feels wrong.

I can also use the solution provided in [Select Git branch for TeamCity Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415704/select-git-branch-for-teamcity-build), but the issue is that we have a lot of branches with quite heavy names, and this solution allows typo, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have correctly configured `branch specification` in VCS Root settings. In my case:

[image]

2. Go to build configuration, select branch you want to build from and press run:

[image]

[Working with feature branches](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Feature+Branches) from TC docs should be helpful as well.

Hope that helps.

PS: Based on TC 2017.2.1 (build 50732)